# Почему в цикле for некорректно работает оператор in?

Tags: python-3.x, кириллица, jupyter-notebook

День добрый! Есть скачанный из сети через requests список со вложенными словарями (посты на русском из ВК). Одно из значений словаря - список строк. В цикле for при помощи оператора in сравниваю этот список с эталонным (street_names), который загружен из файла, кириллица, utf-8. Не могу понять, отчего часть строк при проверке не опознается как входящая в эталонный список?

```
for j in enumerate(posts_total):
    for i in j[1]['keywords']:
        if i in street_names:
            posts_w_address.append(j[1])
```

Проверяя словари, не вошедшие в нужный мне список posts_w_address, вижу, что среди строк, которые я проверяю, есть ровно те, что включены в эталонный список. То есть на экране я вижу в эталоне и проверяемом словаре две одинаковых строки: 'переулок' или, например 'Бардина'.

Может я должен как-то установить кодировку для скачанного из сети списка?

Jupyter notebook, windows 7.64.

Пример данных.
Фрагмент списка street_names: ['улица', 'адресу', 'Авиационная', 'Ленина'].
Список с нераспознанным ключевым словом:
['Здравствуйте,', '18.04.18', 'в', '10', 'утра', '15', 'минут,', 'был', 'угнан', 'автомобиль', 'марки', 'Honda', 'Crv', '2008', 'года.', 'Угнан', 'по', 'адресу', 'авиационная', '16', 'города', 'Екатеринбург', 'Особые', 'приметы', 'автомобиля', 'это', '1.', 'Рейлинги', 'по', 'кузову', '(металлические', 'трубы', 'снизу)', '2.', 'Вмятина', 'над', 'левой', 'фарой', 'на', 'капоте', '3.', 'Шов', 'пайки', 'бампера', 'под', 'левой', 'фарой', '4.', 'Так', 'же', 'не', 'хватает', 'омывателя', 'фар', '(левого)', '5.', 'Темно', 'синий', 'цвет', 'автомобиля', 'после', 'полировки', 'За', 'любую', 'информацию', 'буду', 'благодарен', 'Писать', 'в', 'ЛС'].
Программа должна была распознать строку 'адресу', но не 'авиационная'.

Comment: приведите в вопросе __воспроизводимый__ пример данных

Comment: Неполный пример данных. Нет, street_names. Впрочем, в коде ничего подозрительного нет, кроме отсутствия break после добавления в posts_w_address. Без него, запись будет добавлена столько раз, сколько совпадет ключевых слов. Поэтому ищите проблему в другом месте. Например, запятая в слове 'Кольцово,' явно помешает идентификации.

Comment: @Lecron В переменной street_names загружен длинный список названий улиц, в том числе и 'Утренний'. Помещать её сюда всю я счел неуместным. Код и в самом деле добавляет в список posts_w_address множество словарей, внутри которых встречается совпадение по кодовым словам. Про запятые я тоже помню, но в данном случае 'Кольцово' нет в street_names.

Comment: Весь список улиц и не нужно. Нужен __минимально__ воспроизводимый фрагмент данных. В идеале, хватит всего трех:  которая должна сработать но не судьба, которая срабатывает штатно и которая не должна сработать.

Comment: @Lecron, я добавил. Но все становится страньше и страньше... Я попробовал сравнивать в обратном порядке. То есть начинать перебирать в цикле for строки эталонного списка и по очереди сравнивать их со строками в анализируемых словарях. Таким макаром программа нашла еще несколько совпадений... Но пример, который я вставил в вопрос все равно остался актуален. Программа не распознала совпадение строк "адресу". Мне кажется, пора менять формулировку вопроса ))

Comment: Если у вас не работает, то действительно становится страньше и страньше. Ибо у меня, копипаста вашего кода и данных, с единственной добавкой `print(i)`, на слово "адресу" реагирует без проблем.